# Possibility to copy file to docker container/image without having to do docker push

Tags: docker

I'd just like to find out whether its possible to use `docker cp` or another method to copy a single file to an image already pushed? (see questions at bottom)

By this I mean I'm making minor tweaks to the source code and every time I have to run `docker build` and `docker push`. This is really inefficient as sometimes the layers are +-500mb (and my internet upload speed is rather slow). I've already tried to use `docker cp app.py <docker-container-id>:<working-dir>/app.py` but the changes aren't reflecting.

1. I know `docker cp` is meant for running containers but then what are its use cases?
2. Is there there a more efficient way to do this or do I really have to build and push a new version each time?

Comment: It is not possibile. The pushed image is immutable by design.

Comment: makes sense. So there's no way around having to push a new image after every small change? I guess the right way would just be to test locally, make sure everything works and then push?

Comment: Yes, you have to push it everytime. But if you have image already running (container) in some environment, you can connect to it and make changes in the already running container (hotfixes). But you ned to know that this changes will be lost after next container restart.

Comment: Ok @czende thank you. I'll try make that work just so I can see changes live.